# On document click identify text, image or div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click I want to identify what is being clicked. Is it `Text` or `Image` or a outer `Div`. According to the result I want to show alert message.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ersaurabh101/b43u72Lp/8/) I have prepared, but I don't know how to identify the same with `if` condition.

```js
 $(document).on("click", function() {
 
 //when clicked want to know if i clicked image or text or  div and accordingly show alert

alert("clicked div");
alert("clicked image");
alert("clicked text");
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pouter">
 
 <div id="change_color" class="jumbo text-center context_menu" style=" padding:20px; " >
 <div  class="col-md-12 context_image sim-row-edit">
 <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/forum-emoticons-20x20/20/Verlegen.png" class="imgtop sim-row-edit"></div>
 <h1 class="sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">My First Bootstrap Page 1</h1>
 <p  contenteditable="true">Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
 </div>
 
    <div class="container cont context_menu sim-row-edit">
 <div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 context_menu">
 <div class="row"><div class="col-md-3 context_image">
 <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/forum-emoticons-20x20/20/Verlegen.png" class="imggbot sim-row-edit"></div>
 
 <div class="col-md-9 small-heading context_menu sim-row-edit context_intLink">
 <span class="sim-row-edit">Column 1</span></h3></div><div class="col-md-12 sim-row-edit"><p class="smalltxt-p0 sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p><p class="smalltxt-p0 sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
 </div></div></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You've asked a question and received answers to that question, but your comment implies that this isn't the *solution* you want.  While it won't affect the accepted answer, can you describe what you're trying to achieve with this as there is likely a better way to handle this.  (or confirm it was for purely educational reasons (while learning js/jquery)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any event listener, you can acccess the event object which is automatically passed to the listener. The event object has a `target` property which holds a reference to the element that the event was raised on:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  const clickedTag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()
  switch (clickedTag) {
    case 'div': alert('div clicked!'); break;
    case 'p': console.log('you clicked on a paragraph'); break;
    case 'img': console.log('this time it was an image that was clicked.'); break;
    default: console.log(`${clickedTag} clicked`); 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pouter">

  <div id="change_color" class="jumbo text-center context_menu" style=" padding:20px; ">
    <div class="col-md-12 context_image sim-row-edit">
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/forum-emoticons-20x20/20/Verlegen.png" class="imgtop sim-row-edit"></div>
    <h1 class="sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">My First Bootstrap Page 1</h1>
    <p contenteditable="true">Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container cont context_menu sim-row-edit">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 context_menu">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 context_image">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/forum-emoticons-20x20/20/Verlegen.png" class="imggbot sim-row-edit"></div>

          <div class="col-md-9 small-heading context_menu sim-row-edit context_intLink">
            <span class="sim-row-edit">Column 1</span></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 sim-row-edit">
            <p class="smalltxt-p0 sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p class="smalltxt-p0 sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, got it, and how do i do the same on right click ? something like this - ` $(document).on("contextmenu","div", function(event) {`

Comment: Just exchange the event name then.

Answer (score 1):

As this is tagged [jquery] and uses jquery in the example, you can use `.is()` to check if the element clicked is a specific node type (it doesn't just need to be used with classes/pseudos)

```
if ($(event.target).is("div"))
```

Example snippet (note this is for example only and could be tidied/made more efficient quite easily)

```js
$(document).on("click", function(event) {

  //when clicked want to know if i clicked image or text or  div and accordingly show alert

  if ($(event.target).is("div"))
    console.log("div clicked")

  else if ($(event.target).is("span"))
    console.log("span clicked")
    
  else if ($(event.target).is("p"))
    console.log("p clicked")

  else if ($(event.target).is("h1"))
    console.log("h1 clicked")

  else if ($(event.target).is("img"))
    console.log("img clicked")

  else
    console.log("clicked other")


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pouter">

  <div id="change_color" class="jumbo text-center context_menu" style=" padding:20px; ">
    <div class="col-md-12 context_image sim-row-edit">
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/forum-emoticons-20x20/20/Verlegen.png" class="imgtop sim-row-edit"></div>
    <h1 class="sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">My First Bootstrap Page 1</h1>
    <p contenteditable="true">Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container cont context_menu sim-row-edit">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 context_menu">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 context_image">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/forum-emoticons-20x20/20/Verlegen.png" class="imggbot sim-row-edit"></div>

          <div class="col-md-9 small-heading context_menu sim-row-edit context_intLink">
            <span class="sim-row-edit">Column 1</span></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 sim-row-edit">
            <p class="smalltxt-p0 sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
            <p class="smalltxt-p0 sim-row-edit" contenteditable="true">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use

```
$("*").on("click", function(event) { 

    if ($(this).is("img"))  
        console.log("img clicked")

    ....

    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

note the use of `$("*")` instead of `document` to catch the event on all elements and the user of `event.stopPropagation();` to stop the click bubbling up.

You wouldn't want to use this in "real" code as you generally want those events to bubble up, so just an alternative to show how to use `this` within a global handler / equivalent of `event.target`

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {

if(event.target.tagName == "IMG"){
  alert("Clicked on Image");}
else if(event.target.tagName == "DIV"){
  alert("Clicked on DIV");}
else if(event.target.tagName == "P" || event.target.tagName == "H1"){
  alert("Clicked on TEXT");}
```

});

for text clicking there is no direct way you have clicked on text, it will give the tags, you can all your text tag conditions or you can use else.

Comment: You may want to make yourself familiar with `switch...case` in Javascript.